# creating logfile c#

Tags: c#, logging

can anyone help me in creating a "logfile" to write all the exceptions that occur in C#

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the already suggested frameworks, there is also [built-in tracing support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd83saa2%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Built-in traces are a very good tool, and you can also turn them on and off in runtime using TraceSwtiches. I'll prefer this approach instead of relying on 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

http://logging.apache.org/log4net is the standard tool in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing your own logging framework, you can use one of the following:

[Enterprise Library Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309506.aspx)

[Nlog](http://www.nlog-project.org/)

[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logging framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Answer (score 1):

For logging only exceptions take a look at [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for other logging look at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)